# how to solve (*** Mininet must run as root.) in pycharm?

Tags: python, ubuntu, mininet

I'm completely new to Linux and Python. I want to run a mininet python test file using Pycharm but got the following error

```
*** Mininet must run as root.
```

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Become root!!! To run something as root, first you need root privileges, and then have a look at [the sudo man page](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.28/sudo.man.html).

First see that you have this access:

```
sudo mn
```

If this works then `ctrl+c`

Then run it like:

```
sudo python miniedit.py
```