# How to run as root in PyCharm in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, pycharm, root, mininet, pythoninterpreter

I followed recommendations from [the following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57716386/how-to-solve-mininet-must-run-as-root-in-pycharm) but I did not get the result. The problem is that, I am unable to add the new python-sudo.sh file to the interpreter path. The path of the new python-sudo.sh is `/home/user_name/python-sudo.sh`.The `Ok` button is not getting activated in the interpreter add window as shown in picture:
[Mininet should be run as root user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcN29.png)

Comment: Basic formatting and grammar changes

Comment: Welcome to SO. Down votes indicate that people can not understand the problem as described. Are you having problem running PyCharm as root or did you run it as root and it didn't help? If it didn't help, are you sure you ran as root and what exact commands did you use? If you are sure, then the question is wrongly stated: you should have asked how to add pyhon-sudo.sh to the interpreter path. Lastly, if I'd know the answer, I'd try to help, so this is just to help you get answers from those who know.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that it is not what you really want but it works for me

```
sudo pycharm-professional
```

or

```
sudo pycharm-ce
```

**This will lead you to running pycharm by another user (root)**